# Web crawler attempt

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I attempted to make a web crawler for getting all links in a website, i would expect it to keep going till it gathers and crawls all links but it stops after a very short period of time and i'm not sure why. Thank you in advance !

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

queue = set()
crawled = set()
DOMAIN = 'https://www.ebay.com/'

def finder(url):
    global crawled, queue, DOMAIN
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}
    queue.add(url)
    
if url not in crawled:
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        crawled.add(url)
        for link in links:
            try:
                new_url = DOMAIN + link.get('href')
                print('Queue: ' + str(len(queue)) + ' | ' + 'Crawled: ' + str(len(crawled)))
                print(new_url)
                queue.add(new_url)

            except:
                return ''
        for each in set(queue):
            try:
                finder(each)
            except:
                return ''

    return queue, crawled


my_finder = finder(DOMAIN)
```

Comment: What do you mean *if* it doesn't? Give a [mre], what's the specific problem?

Comment: Thanks for that, just updated my desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

queue = set()
crawled = set()
DOMAIN = 'https://www.ebay.com/'


def finder(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}
    queue.add(url)

    if url not in crawled:
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        crawled.add(url)
        for link in links:
            try:
                new_url = link.get('href')
                print('Queue: ' + str(len(queue)) + ' | ' + 'Crawled: ' + str(len(crawled)))
                print(new_url)
                queue.add(new_url)
            except:
                return ''
        for each in set(queue):
            try:
                finder(each)
            except:
                return ''

    return queue, crawled


finder(DOMAIN)
```

Sample output (shortened for brevity):

```
Queue: 1 | Crawled: 1
#mainContent
Queue: 2 | Crawled: 1
https://www.ebay.com/
Queue: 2 | Crawled: 1
https://www.ebay.com/sch/ebayadvsearch
Queue: 3 | Crawled: 1
https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&_trksid=m570.l3348
Queue: 4 | Crawled: 1
https://www.ebay.com/deals
Queue: 5 | Crawled: 1
https://www.ebay.com/b/Brand-Outlet/bn_7115532402
...
```

Also, try not to use bare `exception`. The `except` clause(s) specify one or more exception handlers.

Comment: I figured that was probably something wrong with my network, thanks for the tip too ! Any idea why almost none of the links work when i click them ? It gives a page saying "we couldn't find this page"

Comment: It's because you are concatenating the main URL with the found URL in new_url = DOMAIN + link.get('href') I've updated the answer.